# How do I select a value from a dropdownlist case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I am trying to find "CAT" in a dropdown where the values of the dropdown are ["Cat","Rat","Mat"] as a result am not a able find by text and i dont have ID for "CAT" to find by id. Any suggestion?

**EDIT:** lowercase() will change "CAT" to cat right?? But my dropdown has "Cat"

Comment: can you show some code..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compare values [lowercase](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) :

```
if(myvalue.toLowerCase() === ddl[i].toLowerCase()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: lowercase() will change "CAT" to cat right?? But my dropdown has "Cat"

Comment: @Oscar yes that's why I change both sides to lowercase :)

Answer (score 1):

Little late, and is basically what Mysteryos answer is following up with jsFiddle to back it.

This function will return the option back:

```
function Find(searchContent)
{
    var options = $('#dropDown option'); 
    var foundOption;
    $.each(options, function (key, value)
           {
               value = $(value);
               if(value.html().toLowerCase() == searchContent.toLowerCase())
               {
                  foundOption = value;
               }
           });
    return foundOption;
}
```

See a working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/7fWxZ/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

**HTML Code:**

```
<select id="ats">
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Rat</option>
  <option>Mat</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
function findmyat(comparetext){
  $('#ats option').each(function(){
     if ($(this).val().toLowerCase()==comparetext.toLowerCase()){
         //found the option i  was looking for, do what i want
         alert($(this).val()+' has been found');
     }
  }
}
```